# How to validate dash-separated values using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with digits and separators.
The digits may either be separated by a  `comma` or a `hyphen`. But there may never be two digits that are both separated by hyphens without a comma in between.

Example:

valid: `123,12,2,1-3,1,1-3,1`

invalid: `123,12,2,1-3,1,1-3-5,1`

I have a regex that almost works, except it does not detect those `1-3-5` invalid lines.

How can I improve the following?

```
^([0-9])+((,|-)[0-9]+)*$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can decompose your input:

- normal: one or more digits, optionally followed by a dash then one or more digits;
- special: a comma.

The regex for the normal case can be written as `\d+(?:-\d+)?`; for the special case, this is simply `,`.

Applying the `normal* (special normal*)*` pattern, and adding anchors and quantifiers, we have:

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?(,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution:

```
^(?:\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,|$))+$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gO7yT8/1)

Explanation: Match a number, optionally followed by a dash and another number, then match either a comma or the end of the string. And repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You can add condition using look-around which will search for `-digits-` so your regex can look like:

```
^(?!.*-\\d+-)[0-9]+([,-][0-9]+)*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^-negative look-ahead, match will fail if there is any -digits- in your string
```

Comment: @alphabravo use `\d` instead of `\\d`. In Java ``\`` needs to be also escaped in String so I written it this way.

Comment: I see, you had to add the `^` anchor as well.

Comment: @alphabravo I added `^` and `$` anchors just now to be explicit, but they are implicit in `string.matcher(regex)` method which I assume OP is using, so `string.matches("(?!.*-\\d+-)[0-9]+([,-][0-9]+)*")` will work the same as `string.matches("^(?!.*-\\d+-)[0-9]+([,-][0-9]+)*$")`.